# Where to get the kernel source directory Kali Linux

Tags: linux, symbolic-link, kernel

This is a branch off of this question: [Installing new driver on Linux, missing the 'Build' directory](https://superuser.com/questions/952688/installing-new-driver-on-linux-missing-the-build-directory)

Since the PC has no internet I can not use `apt-get` to rebuild the kernel and get the linux headers. However, the /Build path is simply a symlink to a directory containing files on how to compile things, so if I can download the build directory's contents on a internet-capable computer, I can simply put them on a USB and drop them where they should have been originally and run the driver compiler again. Does anyone know where to download the contents of the Kali kernel source directory (the path is: "/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build", which is a symlink)

Answer (score 0):

I looked it up then noticed the question was 7 years old...
But your question answered my reason for finding this link..

```
    uname -r = 5.18.0-kali5-amd64

    /lib/modules/5.18.0-kali5-amd64/build -> /usr/src/linux-headers-5.18.0-kali5-amd64

    /lib/modules/5.18.0-kali5-amd64/source -> /usr/src/linux-headers-5.18.0-kali5-common

    /usr/lib/modules/5.18.0-kali5-amd64/build -> /usr/src/linux-headers-5.18.0-kali5-amd64

    /usr/lib/modules/5.18.0-kali5-amd64/source -> /usr/src/linux-headers-5.18.0-kali5-common
```